# How do I fix "Computed property ... was assigned to but it has no setter" error in Buefy b-table component using Vuex store

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, buefy, mapstatetoprops

**Situation**:

I have a VueJS2 app with an array of items in my Vuex store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
       checkedItems: []
    }
   ...
```

The idea is to have the checked (selected) items in a buefy b-table component globally available through this array. The b-table is initiated in my component like so:

```
 <b-table
   ...
   :checked-rows.sync="checkedItems"
   ...
```

and the store's state is mapped within the component like so:

```
...
  computed: {
     ...mapState(['checkedItems'])
   },
  ...
```

**Problem**:

The rows get selected visually (i.e. the checkbox toggles between checked/ clear) but the checkedItems array of the store does not get updated. I know this because for debugging I display a count for the array and it remains zero no matter how many items I (de-)select. The browser console shows "[Vue warn]: Computed property "checkedFrqs" was assigned to but it has no setter." when I select a row.

I notice however it works when I manually push an entry in one of the components methods viz:

```
this.checkedItems.push(row)
```

**Question**:

How do I get

```
:checked-rows.sync="checkedItems"
```

to work seamlessly for the Vuex array? (P.S. when I use a local array instead of the Vuex store's array, everything also works)

Comment: I think that error happens when you try to change a computed property

Comment: By the way, take a look at this https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html. Vuex variables have to be updated using mutations.

Comment: thanks, that gave me a clue

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, this solved it:

```
:checked-rows.sync="$store.state.checkedItems"
```

(not using the getters->mapState)